# Why is it that after moving my cursor around really fast for half a second, my cursor becomes huge?

Tags: macos, mouse, trackpad, cursor

If I move my cursor around really fast, half a second after I start moving it the cursor becomes huge. Why does it do that? Can I disable it somewhere in settings?

Note: I noticed it works with a few mice I have tried, and my built-in trackpad. I didn't change any of the default settings that should change this, so you might be able to do it to. If you need proof, I'd be happy to make a video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to System Preferences -> Accessibility and uncheck 'Shake mouse pointer to locate'

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Its a new feature in El Capitan to help you find your cursor in the screen ... its basically for old people.

Comment: Is there any way to disable it?

Comment: @FlareCat Disable it in the Accessibility section of System Preferences.